# Weird Python behavior while using Dictionary and escape characters

Tags: python, ldap, escaping

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to perform simple tasks the way I used to, but I've faced an interesting... feature?

The code below works just how I want it to:

```
def cleanLDAP(search):
  escChars = {'(':r'\28', ')':r'\29' }
  for ch, val in escChars.items():
    if ch in search:
      search = search.replace(ch, val)
  return search

cleanLDAP('(123)')
```

The output is `'\\28123\\29'` as I expect, but when I change `escChars` as follows:

```
escChars = {'(':r'\28', ')':r'\29', '\\': '\5c' }
```

the output become a bit weird: `'\x05c28123\x05c29'`

I understand that I might miss some implicit encoding changes, but still I want to know the reason why does this happening? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the output you expect with the added escape characters? Can you add another input/output example. I wasn't able to reproduce

Comment: I need an LDAP compatible string where escape characters changed with it's analogs e.g. "(telephoneNumber=(123)4567890)" should look like "(telephoneNumber=\28123\294567890)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5c` in `utf-8` is `\`.

When you try save a string as `\5c` Python returns the `utf-8` hex for `5c` since you prefixed the string with `\` this causes your value to become: `\x05c`.

```
'\5c'
#'\x05c'

'5c'
#'5c'

escChars
#{'(': '\\28', ')': '\\29', '\\': '\x05c'}
```

When you iterate over your keys, the `ch` it tests against in your iteration is `\`, because you did not save your key with the `raw` format string `r`.

```
for ch, value in escChars.items(): 
    print(ch, value)

#( \28
#) \29
#\ c
```

Finally, since you are modifying your everytime you find a match during iteration, you're checking if the `\` exists **after** you added it in via `replace()`

This leads you to do your first replacement, then replaces the `\` you inserted into the string with the `utf-8` symbol for `\`.

The simple fix here is to save your key with the `r` to ensure the code will only match against `\\` and not `\`, and save your value with the same to ensure it does not get converted to hex.

```
def cleanLDAP(search):
    escChars = {'(':r'\28', ')':r'\29', r'\\': r'\5c' }
    for ch, val in escChars.items():
        if ch in search:
            search = search.replace(ch, val)
    return search

>>> cleanLDAP('(123)')

#'\\28123\\29'
```

Comment: This explains everything, thank you very much! I thought about adding "r" to keys as well, but didn't expect that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Change to -

```
escChars = {'(':r'\28', ')':r'\29', '\\': r'\5c' }
```

You missed adding `r'\5c'` and just did `'\5c'`. This makes it hexadecimal.

To understand with an example -

```
a='\5'
a
ord(a)
```

Returns `'\x05'` and `5` respectively

Comment: My bad, I missed prefix "r", but it's not the cause.